# Convert LLVM IR to JSON

Tags: json, llvm, llvm-ir

It seems that the [Python bindings to LLVM only allow creating IR, not parsing LLVM IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911469/how-to-parse-llvm-ir-in-python?noredirect=1#comment125365335_70911469).  This means that Python (and similar languages) cannot be used to analyze LLVM IR.  Is there a way to turn LLVM IR into JSON? This would be easily loaded into Python (and virtually any other language) and make it easy to use those languages to analyze LLVM programs, without having to create bindings for each language individually,

Comment: It's open source. Extend the python wrappers; that's how they got to their current state too. Then please make a pull request.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea...